# Virtual Disk 00 Shows Degraded for PowerEdgeR710: Does my Disk where okay?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid

My Virtual Disk  State shows me Degraded and once i double click both the disk seems to me fine

Moreover, under Connector 0 my physical disk 0.0.0 showing Forign State.

I am new to this and can someone tell me whats going with my disk

Thank you

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it. Consider reading he manuals as a starting point.

Comment: @TomTom   , Which manual i need to refer.

Comment: You have hardware. Hardware has manual. YOu haven no maual, call manufacturer or learn google.

Comment: @TomTom , Hardware Manual doesnt seems to help me. Can u share me any link for initial troubleshooting , from the logs its clear that rebuilt has failed for my RAID5

Answer (score 1):

If one of your disk is marked as "Foreign", it means that the RAID controller did not include it in the current array because it *seems* a member of another ("foreign") array.

From the RAID controller BIOS, OMSA or iDRAC you can clear the disk's foreign config and import it into the array. However, extreme care should be used because any error can bring down the entire array, with a catastrophic data loss.

Comment: I have noticed, in my logs there is a  " The Controller write policy has changed to write through, Battery 0 ,Controller 0

Comment: This has nothing to do with the foreign disk. I strongly suggest you to solve one problem at time. Moreover, please download the PERC user guide and read it.

Comment: Now i am rebuilding the disk . its ongoing now